# Bullets to slideToggle external divs

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have this bit of code which I use to easily slideToggle 3 divs:

```
$(function () {
    $('.service-title').click(function () {
        $(this).next('.service-text').slideToggle();

        $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
        return false;
    });
});
```

The divs are marked up as followed (three times):

```
<div class="service-item">
    <div class="service-title"><h3>Title</h3></div>

    <div class="service-text">Text</div>
</div>
```

This works perfectly. However, the project I'm working on requires me to add  an image with 3 bullets next to it. These bullets (`.bullet-1`, `.bullet-2` and `.bullet-3`) are divs positioned above the image and clicking each of them have to open either the first, second or third `.service-item`. These divs are, however, not in the same parent div and I don't know how to target the corresponding toggle div by clicking on the bullet div.

The complete HTML mark-up:

```
<div class="colgroup-2">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="services-image">
            <img />

            <div class="bullet-1"></div>
            <div class="bullet-2"></div>
            <div class="bullet-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="wrapper"> <!-- / used to vertically align content -->
            <div class="service-item">
                <div class="service-title"><h3>Title</h3></div>

                <div class="service-text">Text</div>
            </div>

            <div class="service-item">
                <div class="service-title"><h3>Title</h3></div>

                <div class="service-text">Text</div>
            </div>

            <div class="service-item">
                <div class="service-title"><h3>Title</h3></div>

                <div class="service-text">Text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in your case:

```
$(function(){
    $('[class*="bullet"]').on('click', function(){
        var relatedIndex = $('[class*="bullet"]').index($(this));
        $('.service-item').not($('.service-item').eq(relatedIndex)).slideUp();
        $('.service-item').eq(relatedIndex).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('[class*="bullet"]').on('click', function(){
    var relatedIndex = $('[class*="bullet"]').index($(this));
    $('.service-item').not($('.service-item').eq(relatedIndex)).slideUp();
    $('.service-item').eq(relatedIndex).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.service-item { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="colgroup-2">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="services-image">
            <img />

            <div class="bullet-1">&#8226;</div>
            <div class="bullet-2">&#8226;</div>
            <div class="bullet-3">&#8226;</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="wrapper"> <!-- / used to vertically align content -->
            <div class="service-item">
                <div class="service-title"><h3>Title 1</h3></div>

                <div class="service-text">Text 1</div>
            </div>

            <div class="service-item">
                <div class="service-title"><h3>Title 2</h3></div>

                <div class="service-text">Text 2</div>
            </div>

            <div class="service-item">
                <div class="service-title"><h3>Title 3</h3></div>

                <div class="service-text">Text 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! By adding `.find('.service-text')` after both instances of `eq(relatedIndex)` to your code I managed to get this working perfectly. Thank you :)